# Java: detect control characters which are not correct for JSON

Tags: java, json, unicode, control-characters

I am reinventing the wheel and creating my own JSON parse methods in Java.

I am going by the (very nice!) documentation on [json.org](http://www.json.org/). The only part I am unsure about is where it says ***"or control character"***

Since the documentation is so clear, and JSON is so simple and easy to implement, I thought I would go ahead and require the spec instead of being loose.

How would I **correctly** strip out control characters in Java? Perhaps there is a unicode range?

[image]

---

### Edit: A (commonly?) missing peice to the puzzle

I [have been informed](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/11097/764) that there are other control characters outside of [the defined range](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isISOControl%28int%29) [<sup>1</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6051582/463304) [<sup>2</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6051594/463304) that can be troublesome in `<script>` tags.

> Most notably the characters U+2028 and U+2029, Line and Paragraph Separator, which act as newlines. Injecting a newline into the middle of a string literal will most likely cause a syntax error (unterminated string literal). [<sup>3</sup>](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/11097/764)

Though I believe this does not pose an XSS threat, it is still a good idea to add extra rules for the use in `<script>` tags.

- Just be simple and encode all non-"ASCII printable" characters with `\u` notation. Those characters are uncommon to begin with. If you like, you could add to the white-list, but I do recommend a white-list approach.
- In case you are not aware, **do not forget** about `</script` (not case sensitive), which **could cause HTML script injection** to your page with the characters `</script><script src=http://tinyurl.com/abcdef>`. None of those characters are by default encoded in JSON.

Comment: Unicode is Unicode. UTF-16 is an encoding. I think Java has tests for Unicode groupings? See [the Character class documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html) for some preamble stuff and other interesting functions.

Comment: What I mean is, every character in a Java string is two bytes. Even if the data is ASCII, when converted to a string, it ends up two bytes per string.

Comment: *"For those who don't know, Java operates with UTF-16 characters."* Well, yes, sort of. Java's `String` type stores string data internally in UTF-16, but Java is perfectly happy reading and writing using other encodings (including UTF-8 or Windows-1252 -- both commonly used -- and UTF-32). May be worth starting here: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

Comment: Don't worry, I understand string encoding even if I am not describing it right.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Will [Character.isISOControl(...)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isISOControl%28int%29) do? Incidentally, UTF-16 is an encoding of Unicode codepoints... Are you going to be operating at the byte level, or at the character/codepoint level? I recommend leaving the mapping from UTF-16 to character streams to Java's core APIs...

Comment: I am operating at the character level. Bytes are converted to string before the JSON parse begins.

Comment: I don't know if `isISOControl` is correct or not. I know it will do because this does not need to be strictly correct. :)

Comment: @George: Well, the docs say *"A character is considered to be an ISO control character if its code is in the range `'\u0000'` through `'\u001F'` or in the range `'\u007F'` through `'\u009F'`"* As that matches the definition I linked to of a Unicode control character, I'd say @Dilum is on a winner... :-) (Though being the pedant I am, I'd probably want to find a reference saying that the two really were linked, so that if one changes, I don't have to worry about them getting out of sync.) But that's probably pedantry.

Comment: @T.J.: +1 to you and jarnbjo. Accepting Dilum's answer because that is what I ended up using.

Comment: @George: Entirely reasonable! :-)

Answer (score 6):

Even if it's not very specific, I would assume that they refer to the ["control" character category](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Cc/index.htm) from the Unicode specification.

In Java, you can check if a character `c` is a Unicode control character with the following expression: `Character.getType(c) == Character.CONTROL`.

Answer (score 5):

I know the question has been asked a couple of years ago, but I am replying anyway, because the accepted answer is not correct.

```
Character.isISOControl(int codePoint)
```

does the following check:

```
(codePoint >= 0x00 && codePoint <= 0x1F) || (codePoint >= 0x7F && codePoint <= 0x9F);
```

The JSON specification defines at https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7159:

> 7. Strings
>
> The representation of strings is similar to conventions used in the C
> family of programming languages.  A string begins and ends with
> quotation marks.  All Unicode characters may be placed within the
> quotation marks, except for the characters that must be escaped:
> quotation mark, reverse solidus, and **the control characters (U+0000
> through U+001F).**

```
Character.isISOControl(int codePoint)
```

will flag all characters that need to be escaped `(U+0000-U+001F)`, though it will also flag characters that do not need to be escaped `(U+007F-U+009F)`.  It is not required to escape the characters `(U+007F-U+009F)`.

Answer (score 4):

I believe [the Unicode definition of a control character](http://unicode.org/glossary/#control_codes) is:

> The 65 characters in the ranges U+0000..U+001F and U+007F..U+009F.

That's their definition of a *control code*, but the above is followed by the sentence *"Also known as control characters."*, so...