# Go: What's the best way to detect invalid JSON string characters?

Tags: json, string, go, unicode, control-characters

What's the best, most efficient way to detect whether a Go string contains characters that are invalid in JSON strings? In other words, what's the Go equivalent to this answer to this [Java question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6051509/79202)? Is it just to use
[strings.ContainsAny](https://golang.org/pkg/strings/#ContainsAny) (assuming the [ASCII control characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#Control_characters))?

```
ctlChars := string([]byte{
    0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18,
    19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 127,
})
if strings.ContainsAny(str, ctlChars) {
    println("has control chars")
}
```

Comment: Efficient in what sense? Fast? Lowest power consumption? Least number of CPU instructions? Runs on Nacl? Least duration/Watt? Least number of cache misses? Easy to understand? Most efficient during debugging? Easiest to change of the JSON spec changes?

Comment: @Volker Yes. Would be useful to know/see/document all the options and tradeoffs.

Comment: "All the options and tradeoffs" is pretty broad. If you have a particular optimization target that might be narrow enough to answer on SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking to identify control characters (as in the answers to the Java question you pointed to), you might want to use `unicode.IsControl` for a simpler solution.

https://golang.org/pkg/unicode/#IsControl

```
func containsControlChar(s string) bool {
    for _, c := range s {
        if unicode.IsControl(c) {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/Pr_9mmt-th